# How I deploy my google glass app

Tags: google-glass, google-mirror-api

I build a google glass app using mirror api.

Now I want to deploy my app in glassware. I think I need a JAVA-server enable maven.
What else do I need? Is there any special configuration for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general you can deploy a Mirror API Glassware to any web server is capable of running it.

However, from your question I gather that you used the Java quick start project to create your Glassware. This gives you a couple of options:

- Use a servlet container like [Apache Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/). Install it per their instructions, build your project as a war file using maven, `mvn war:war`, and then install the war file on Tomcat.
- Use Jetty. The quick start project's `pom.xml` file includes the [Jetty maven plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Maven+Jetty+Plugin). You probably used this in development, can use it the same way on a deployed server. Just copy the whole source tree over and fire it up with maven: `mvn jetty:run`.